# Open new form in existing window

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to open a new form in an existing window. I have 2 forms, Menu and Customers.

```
private void CustomersView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Customers form_customers = new Customers();
        form_customers.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

If I use this code to open the new form, is it possible to open the new form in the existing window?

Greet,
Henk-Jan Leusink

Comment: what you exactly want? you can use mdi form in the background. is that what you mean?

Comment: In the window? I think what you want is a user control. A custom control that way you can add it to the window your in.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no. Each `Form` subclass instance is meant to represent an actual Win32 top-level window.

If you want to load another set of controls into an existing window, then you should use UserControls. Create a new UserControl in VS and copy or move your controls from your `customers` form class into your new UserControl. Add the UserControl to your main form's designer but set its visiblity to hidden. When you want to show it just change the visibility setting.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a **`MDI`** form, set [`IsMdiContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer.aspx) property of main window to `true` and try using it like this code:

```
// This is a method on the MDI parent (IsMdiContainer = true)
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myForm = new MyForm();
    myForm.MdiParent = this;
    myForm.Show();
}
```